# Showing alert after page reload for inserted data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want to show the alert message after I add a row that says -

```
"Data added successfully".
```

But adding a row also requires to reload the page in order to get the added data. So because of the reload, I am not able to get the message alert.

**HTML:**

```
<alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" 
type="{{alert.type}}" close="closeAlert($index)">{{alert.msg}}</alert>
```

**Controller:**

```
dataAPIService.addData(JSON.stringify($scope.rows)).success(function(response) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast("addData", $scope.data);
        ngDialog.close('ngdialog1');
        $route.reload();
        $scope.$parent.alerts.length=0;
        $scope.$parent.alerts.push({type: 'success',msg: 'Data added successfully'});
    });
```

**NOTE:**

If I comment out `$route.reload()` then it works fine but then I won't get added data. So I need to reload the page and still want to get the alert.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put some state in a place that won't be erased by an Angular route reload. Some options are:

1. In an Angular service (careful, global state)
2. In the URL (e.g as a query param)
3. In local storage (hard to do it right)
4. ... in your database :)

In your case, I would say option 1 is the right balance between robust and affordable.